# How can I get the ingredient name(s) for those ingredients with the highest number of allergens?

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ingredient_tbl
(
ingredient_id VARCHAR (3),
ingredient_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
ingredient_decription VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ingredient_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (ingredient_id)
);

CREATE TABLE allergen_ingredient_link_tbl /* One ingredient contains 0 to many allergen. One allergen is in 1 to many ingredient. */
(
ingredient_id VARCHAR (3),
allergen_id VARCHAR (3),
FOREIGN KEY (allergen_id) REFERENCES allergen_tbl(allergen_id),
FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES ingredient_tbl(ingredient_id),
PRIMARY KEY (ingredient_id, allergen_id)
);
```

My sql query so far, which counts the number of allergens and orders the list:

```
SELECT ingredient_name, COUNT(link.allergen_id) "Number of Allergens"
FROM ingredient_tbl i
INNER JOIN allergen_ingredient_link_tbl link
    ON link.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id
GROUP BY ingredient_name
ORDER BY "Number of Allergens" DESC;
```

i've tried this but, it only returns the max value. I can't work out how to return the ingredient name(s) too:

```
SELECT MAX("Number of Allergens")
    FROM
        (SELECT ingredient_name, COUNT(link.allergen_id) "Number of Allergens"
        FROM ingredient_tbl i
        INNER JOIN allergen_ingredient_link_tbl link
            ON link.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id
        GROUP BY ingredient_name
        ORDER BY "Number of Allergens" DESC);
```

Comment: Use your previous query (the one without the `MAX` and use `LIMIT 1` to only retrieve the first row.

Comment: what does `select version();` give?

Comment: VARCHAR(3) is a bizarre choice for an id

Comment: Why is VARCHAR(3) a bizarre choice for an ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT ingredient_name, COUNT(link.allergen_id) "Number of Allergens"
FROM ingredient_tbl i JOIN
    Iallergen_ingredient_link_tbl link
    ON link.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id
GROUP BY ingredient_name
ORDER BY "Number of Allergens" DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note:  This returns only one ingredient with the maximum.  If you want ties, you can use window functions.

EDIT:

If you want to handle ties, use `RANK()`:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM (SELECT ingredient_name, COUNT(*) "Number of Allergens",
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ingredient_tbl i JOIN
          Iallergen_ingredient_link_tbl link
          ON link.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id
      GROUP BY ingredient_name
     ) i
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: What if more than one ingredient has the max value of allergens? Also, how could I output this as a statement, such as "The ingredient(s) with the highest number of allergens is/are" + ingredient_name(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help.
My final, working query is:

```
SELECT 'Ingredient(s) with most allergens are: ' || ingredient_name || ', with ' || MAX("Number_of_Allergens") || ' each.' 
FROM (
    SELECT ingredient_name, COUNT(link.allergen_id) "Number_of_Allergens",
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(link.allergen_id) DESC) as rank_num
    FROM ingredient_tbl i 
    JOIN allergen_ingredient_link_tbl link
        ON link.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id
    GROUP BY ingredient_name
     ) 
WHERE rank_num = 1
GROUP BY ingredient_name;
```